# Restore multiple backup files created with find followed by sed

Tags: sed, grep, find, xargs

I need to edit files with specific pattern in their names. These files are spread across multiple hierarchical directories.

I am using `find` followed by `sed` with the help of `xargs` to achieve the same as follows:

```
find . -type f -name "file*" | sed -i.bak 's/word1/replace_word1/g'
```

My problem is that now I want to revert back the changes from backup files (**.bak*). Sample directory tree will look like as shown below. I am looking for linux command (may be a chain) to achieve the same.

```
$ tree
.
|-- pdir1
|   |-- dir1
|   |   |-- dir2
|   |   |   |-- file2
|   |   |   `-- file2.bak
|   |   |-- file1
|   |   `-- file1.bak
|   `-- dir3
|       |-- file3
|       `-- file3.bak
`-- pdir2
    |-- file1
    `-- file1.bak
```

I can find all backup files using following `find` command. But can't figure out what to do next. It would be appreciable if your could help me solve this.

```
find . -type f -name "file*.bak"
```

**Note**

I observe this problem as general scenario. I had faced this many times but got away with writing a small wrapper script for it. Here I am hoping for a generic and concise solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option could be use `rename` with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.bak" -exec rename 's/\.bak$//' {} \;
```

This would not rename `foo.bak` if `foo` exists.  In order to force overwriting, use the `-f` option for `rename`:

```
find . -type f -name "*.bak" -exec rename -f 's/\.bak$//' {} \;
```

EDIT: If you can't use `rename`, try:

```
find . -name "*.bak" -exec sh -c 'mv -f $0 ${0%.bak}' {} \;
```

Explanation of the above (last) command: For each result returned by `find`, a shell command is invoked that takes the result as a parameter (denoted by `{}`) for `mv -f $0 ${0%.bak}`.  `$0` is a positional parameter and `${0%.bak}` denotes [shell parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for removing `.bak` from the end of the parameter.  In effect, for a result `foo.bak`, the shell would issue a command `mv -f foo.bak foo`.

Comment: Can't get it working :( `man rename` doesn't show any `-f` option. Is it possible through `mv`?

Comment: Thanks! that works fine. How does `${0%.bak}` work, I mean syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You can restore simply with a `for` loop that traverse directories. It doesn't check if the file without the `bak` extension exists.

```
for f in **/*.bak; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.bak}"; done
```

Comment: `**/*.bak` only works for files located in proper directory structure. I have files spread across. May be I will change given example to more complicated one